# How do I count the number of elements by classname, and turn the result into a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to count how many of an element I have, but I'm not having much luck. Element sample:

`<textarea type="text" data-class-changer="question" class="questioninputcss" data-integer-question="866"></textarea>`

Moving on to my code,

I've tried two things. Here's the first, with its response:

```
        var testCountPre = document.getElementByClassName('questioninputcss');
        var testCount = testCountPre.getElementsByTagName('textarea').length;
```

`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

---

And the second, with its response:

```
    var testCount = ($(".questioninputcss textarea").length);
    var_dump(testCount);
```

`Number(1) 0`

Edit for clarification: I'm using a var_dump script that works in javascript.

Comment: Are you sure your javascript is loaded after DOM elements?

Comment: @PragneshChauhan It is, but I have a script that adds this to functionality to javascript. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery, combine the selectors like below. Your script is trying to find `textarea` elements which are descendants of an element with class `questioninputcss`

```
var testCount = $("textarea.questioninputcss").length;
```

Without jQuery, use [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll)

```
var testCount = document.querySelectorAll('textarea.questioninputcss').length;
```

[getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.getElementsByClassName)(there is a spelling mistake in your code) returns a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), so it does not have a method named [getElementsByTagName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.getElementsByTagName)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
($("textarea.questioninputcss").length);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```js
var testCount = ($("textarea.questioninputcss").length);
console.log(testCount);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea type="text" data-class-changer="question" class="questioninputcss" data-integer-question="866"></textarea>
```